# Excel - Determine if several criteria are met

Tags: excel, offset

I have a column of 1241 values ranging from 1 - 3. What I need to do, for example, is the following:

Check if the cell is equal to 3. If the check is true, check if the associated value 18 columns to the left is equal(OR CONTAINS!) a specific string. I thought something like this:

```
=COUNTIF(S2:S1242,  OFFSET(S2:S1242, 0, -18) = "StringToCheck")
```

But it did not work. I know how to do this if I were to take a column and check each row individually and then sum the 1241 values, but there has to be a simpler way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try array formulas or [`SUMIFS`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to count how many rows meet both criteria, and that you are using Excel 2007 or above:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A7,3,D1:D7,"Hello")
```

If you are using Excel 2003 or below then it requires an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A7=3,IF(D1:D7="Hello",1,0),0))
```

use `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` (rather then just Enter) to complete the formula. This signifies that it is an array-formula.

Comment: I am confused on how this function performs its task. As a test, I created two fields with values 1-5 and tried using the forumla. Does the COUNTIFS() formula check the criteria together in a "AND" fashion, or in some other way?

Comment: That is, does the count increment if criteria1 and criteria2 are simultaneiously met? The reason I am confused is because for my example it appeared as if the result was only incremented if criteria1 was met with its associated range, as well as criteria2 and range2.

Comment: In contrast to the documentation on Microsoft's website. _Each range's criteria is applied one cell at a time. If all of the first cells meet their associated criteria, the count increases by 1. If all of the second cells meet their associated criteria, the count increases by 1 again, and so on until all of the cells are evaluated._

Comment: The above documentation from Microsoft almost makes it sound as if the count is only incremented if all cells meet the criteria.

Comment: You should test it, of course, but the counting is done *in parallel*. That is, it looks at the first two cells (in the two separate ranges) and only increments the count if both criteria are met. This is also why the two ranges have to be the same size. I agree about the documentation as well - it is misleading/wrong.

Comment: Well, I did test and confirm this works. The count is incremented by 1 iff the associated criteria is met simultaneously. I did not even consider this function because of the documentation. I appreciate the help.